Which protocol is necessary for edge to auto launch an application without prompt?
I'm trying to open up specific contacts in the windows 10 whatsapp application using vba and a Microsoft Access database. Opening these links first opens Edge and then opens whatsapp. However, Edge is always prompting that 'A website wants to open this application', which I need to disable for the application to work.

I've added the latest Edge policies (22H2) to my PC and edit them via Local Group Policy Editor: Administrative Templates -> Microsoft Edge ->Define a list of protocols that can launch an external application from listed origins without prompting the user
Here, I've enabled the policy and added the following as an option/protocol
[{"allowed_origins": [ "*" ],"protocol": "whatsapp"}]

The link that I'm trying to open
whatsapp://

Inside of edge I am able to see that the policy has been adjusted and the protocol has been saved using edge://policy/ and edge://settings/content/applicationLinks


However, the whatsapp link still prompts me the same message. Is there anything wrong? Did I forget a setting?
I've used the following pages as guides so far: Imad.dk Microsoft library pureinfotech.com

According to your description, you have configured the "Define a list of protocols that can launch an external application from listed origins without prompting the user" policy, and you can see that this policy has been configured successfully in "edge://policy". In my test (I wrote a simple site that can redirect to "WhatsApp" and hosted it on IIS), I can reproduce this prompt pop-up window. Then I deployed this policy (using the value in your screenshot) to make this pop-up window disappear. So, the value of the policy is correct. However, you can also try to change the "allowed_origins" value to the URL of the site where these links are located to see if it works.
So,what is your Edge version? Please provide sample code for opening the app and the specific origin. Have you tried it on other machines to see if it works?
You also can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#autolaunchprotocolsfromorigins

Based on your answer, I've tried the same thing on a different PC. The whatsapp application did not open at all using the 'whatsapp://' URL. That got me thinking that maybe that URL is not universally used. I've found a different one that opens up without prompting using the settings in my original post. Thanks for the help.

It seems that I was able to fix this issue myself by using a different URL. The same settings as in my original post.
Instead of using
whatsapp://send?phone=xxxxxxxxx&text=something

use this:
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=xxxxxx&text=something

Sadly, due to stability issues with typing the message in the whatsapp application, this idea was left behind. Using this link opens the whatsapp application as expected, but it does not always go to the number asked. Neither does it fill in the number very stable (about 50% of the time).
Instead, I'm now opening
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxx&text=something

Since it will open up the correct person every time and type the message every time. The only thing that I wasn't able to do is to automatically send it (since SENDKEYS is unstable in Access and I couldn't get other solutions such as Selenium to click on SEND).
Hopefully this will help someone else.
